# laravel - save vs saveorfail (real difference in nutshell)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

It's finally time that I understood this concept, because I still don't get some of the cases.

**Question 1)** what does `save()` return? is it always boolean or does it throw exceptions sometimes?

**Question 2)** I am not using any event model. So I don't think `save()` will return false at any time. So it will return true or throw the exception? am I right?

**Question 3)** If I have something like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
  $model1 = new Type();
  $model1->test = 'great';
  $model1->save();

  $model2 = new Type();
  $model2->test2 = 'awesome';
  $model2->save();
  DB::commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
  DB::rollBack();
}
```

Is it possible that save doesn't happen but it doesn't throw the exception? I don't have any events in these models.

**Question 4)** if the answer for the question 3 is 'no it's not possible', then why do i need to use `saveOrFail()`

I'd really appreciate that since I really couldn't find anything that deeply explains what I am asking.

Comment: The source code contains comments which should answer most of your questions: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7593d65436c628c0fbd156b2a22cf15be6a91d39/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L644

Comment: I know, but it doesn't say when it throws exceptions. Would be great if someone experienced would answer my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Question 1)** `save()` can indeed throw exceptions. For example, if you create a model with a decimal column, e.g. 'cost', and try to save a string value in that column, both `save()` and `saveOrFail()` will throw an exception. Demo:

```
>>> $item->cost = 'asdas';
>>> $item->save();
 Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'asdas' for column 'cost' at row 1 (SQL: update ...
```

**Question 2)** Looking through the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master@%7B2019-08-14%7D/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L644), it looks like `save()` will only return `false` when firing either the `saving`, `updating` or `creating` events returns `false`.

Since you haven't defined any event listeners, theoretically yes, you should only ever receive `true` or an exception will be thrown.

**Question 3)** If you're not listening to events then no, it's not possible (at least not probable). The save would only not have happened if there was an exception thrown.

**Question 4)** Since `saveOrFail()` just wraps `save()` in a transaction, its use is to keep the database consistent if any exceptions were raised during the `save()` function. `saveOrFail()` ensures that if there were any exceptions raised during `save()`, the model would not have been saved. `save()` alone would not be able to guarantee that the model was not modified/saved if an exception was thrown.

Since you're already wrapping your code in a transaction, you don't need to use `saveOrFail`.

For your use case, the best I can think of is to call `save()` on all of your models in a single if-expression and to commit the transaction only if the expression is `true`. That way you can cater for both when `save()` returns `false` or when it raises an exception. Like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
  $model1 = new Type();
  $model1->test = 'great';
  
  $model2 = new Type();
  $model2->test2 = 'awesome';
  
  if ($model1->save() && $model2->save()) {
    DB::commit();
  } else {
    DB::rollBack();
  }
} catch(Exception $e){
  DB::rollBack();
}
```

Comment: "***2. The model already exists and isn't "dirty" (i.e. hasn't been modified).***" it still return true. `if (count($dirty) > 0) {..} return true;`

Comment: Nah, I liked your explanations. I myself looked through the official code. and you seem to be right. I only don't understand the fourth answer. difference between save or saveOrFail because if something is wrong, save wouldn't work too and transaction wouldn't be commited. each single save() is transaction by autocommit, remember in mysql?

Comment: I think that, for example, if an exception could be thrown by the `finishSave` method which runs after the model would have been committed to the database (in `performUpdate` or `performInsert`). You would then have an exception to handle, but won't be sure whether the model was updated or not.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57495773 with an answer to Q4: most users do not need `saveOrFail()`. `save()` already throws exceptions, `saveOrFail()` just calls `save()` within a new transaction.

The name of the method is misleading in my opinion. Other Eloquent methods like `find` throw no exceptions, but have a `findOrFail` counterpart that does. This is not the case with `save` and `saveOrFail` as viewable in the code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L693

```php
    public function saveOrFail(array $options = [])
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->transaction(function () use ($options) {
            return $this->save($options);
        });
    }
```

---

The main use of `saveOrFail()` is if you'd like to recover from a failed DB-side update or insertion. If we take the following schema as an example:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class SaveOrFailDemo extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('save_or_fails', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('word')->unique();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('save_or_fails');
    }
}
```

with this basic model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SaveOrFail extends Model
{
}
```

and this test command:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\SaveOrFail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TrySaveOrFail extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'try:save-or-fail {--fail}';

    public function handle()
    {
        DB::transaction(function () {
            // cleanup old tries
            SaveOrFail::query()->delete();

            $model = new SaveOrFail();

            $saveFunction = $this->option('fail')
                ? fn () => $model->saveOrFail()
                : fn () => $model->save();

            $maxSaveAttempts = 3;
            $word = 'demo';

            // force a UNIQUE violation to occur
            $duplicate = new SaveOrFail();
            $duplicate->word = $word . '0';
            $duplicate->save();

            for ($currentSaveAttempt = 0; $currentSaveAttempt < $maxSaveAttempts; $currentSaveAttempt++) {
                $model->word = $word . $currentSaveAttempt;

                try {
                    $saveFunction();
                    $this->info("Saved! {$model->word}");
                    return $model;
                } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
                    $this->warn($ex->getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Running `php artisan try:save-or-fail` with Postgres will never save `$model`. The first UNIQUE violation causes the transaction to enter an aborted state:

```
application@f72fb45f3bfa:/app$ php artisan try:save-or-fail
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "save_or_fails_word_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (word)=(demo0) already exists. (SQL: insert into "save_or_fails" ("word", "updated_at", "created_at") values (demo0, 2021-06-07 19:39:24, 2021-06-07 19:39:24) returning "id")
SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (SQL: insert into "save_or_fails" ("word", "updated_at", "created_at") values (demo1, 2021-06-07 19:39:24, 2021-06-07 19:39:24) returning "id")
SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (SQL: insert into "save_or_fails" ("word", "updated_at", "created_at") values (demo2, 2021-06-07 19:39:24, 2021-06-07 19:39:24) returning "id")
```

However, since `saveOrFail()` runs in its own transaction, we're able to recover from it:

```
application@f72fb45f3bfa:/app$ php artisan try:save-or-fail --fail
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "save_or_fails_word_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (word)=(demo0) already exists. (SQL: insert into "save_or_fails" ("word", "updated_at", "created_at") values (demo0, 2021-06-07 19:40:16, 2021-06-07 19:40:16) returning "id")
Saved! demo1
```

Unless you're expecting that your DB operation could fail and you will recover from it, there is not much point to use `saveOrFail()`.

Answer (score -1):

**Q1**: `save()` will always return a boolean **source**: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save

**Q2**: `save()`does not throw exceptions

**Q3**: Yes see Q2

**Q4**: Because `saveOrFail()` **does** throw Exceptions which you can handle if needed

Comment: Thank you so much. A little bit and I am ready to get it. 1) so if for save(), something happened on db side, laravel will handle that database's exceptions and still will return boolean for us, right? 2) if saveorfail returns boolean or throws exception ,do i need to have try catch block and also if statement for checking ?

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes you can catch exceptions with try catch, hower Exceptions are for Exceptional behaviour and should not be part of your normal application flow (as a best practise)

Comment: 2) yeah, but imagine i have transactions and in it, i want to save 3 models.  so I use saveOrFail() 3 times for different models. because of transaction, I got catch block which rolls back. Now imagine, the second saveOrFail() didn't throw the exception and just returned boolean, then my transaction loses its sense as rollback won't happen. Does this mean i also have to write 3 if else statements for saveOrFail and also try catch block for transaction?

Comment: I saw that article as well ;) I would use the official guide for Laravel and transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't answer our questions. I am sure you are curious about what I asked too. I want to understand it. Laravel doesn't say anything about that scenario I just said.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query won't be executed as a transaction without starting it as one

Comment: This is incorrect, `save()` **does** throw exceptions. Try this: `(new User(['id' => 'hello']))->save();`. You'll get a `Illuminate\Database\QueryException`

Answer (score -2):

If you want proper error handling then use `saveOrFail()` which has an Exception error message. `save()` just returns a `false` boolean.

Comment: `save()` throws exceptions too. `saveOrFail()` just calls `save()` within a transaction and does not add any additional error handling, as viewable in code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L693

Comment: therefore save() is not the same as saveOrFail(). The fail appended (wrapped) method throws an exception, and the save (a different method) returns a value.